# How to use USBmakebmRequestType in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

To set USB request type in objective-c i use:

`#define USBmakebmRequestType`

For example:

```
IOUSBDevRequest request;
request.bmRequestType = USBmakebmRequestType(kUSBOut, kUSBVendor, kUSBDevice);
```

How do i use this in swift ? There is no fucntion USBmakebmRequestType in swift

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Have you tried translating the code and got stuck somewhere?

Comment: @Cristik there is no fucntion `USBmakebmRequestType` in swift

Comment: `USBmakebmRequestType` is a C-macro and cannot be imported into Swift. You need to find the original definition of the macro, and convert it to Swift function by yourself. If you can successfully find the original definition and add it to your question, someone would help for you or for your bounty.

Comment: @OOPer oh, thanks, i found it in USB.h sources i think. I could convert it my self:)

Comment: Then you'd better write an answer by yourself and accept it. Developers searching with "USBmakebmRequestType" would find this article and the right answer would help them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented it myself:

```
func USBmakebmRequestType(direction:Int, type:Int, recipient:Int) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8((direction & kUSBRqDirnMask) << kUSBRqDirnShift)|UInt8((type & kUSBRqTypeMask) << kUSBRqTypeShift)|UInt8(recipient & kUSBRqRecipientMask)
}
```

Usage:

```
USBmakebmRequestType(direction: kUSBIn, type: kUSBDevice, recipient: kUSBStandard)
```